# JPA - how to model this join with conditions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I was trying to find an answer but, unfortunately, with no luck.

The data structure looks like this:

- TABLE_X - contains userId, also userType telling if this is external or internal user
- INTERNAL_USERS - contains key userId
- EXTERNAL_USERS - also contains key userId

TABLE_X.userId is either INTERNAL_USERS.userId or EXTERNAL_USERS.userId.

Now, I would like to map an entity out of TABLE_X and have user object mapped to correct entity, either INTERNAL_USERS or EXTERNAL_USERS. 
How should I do this?

Should I create two fields and map one to INTERNAL_USERS and one two EXTERNAL_USERS and just see which one is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, what you have to do is to replicate structure of the TABLE_X columns with fields on the TABLE_X class, and add to fields one for INTERNAL_USERS.userID and one for EXTERNAL_USERS.userID

But if you store on TABLE_X.userType if a user is internal or external, I think that the best thing you can do is not create any other table, because you just have the information you need on your first table (TABLE_X). If you want to know all the users that are internal for instance, just do a SQL and select all the values from TABLE_X where userType = "Internal"

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernate inheritance. Check out the Table per class inheritance pattern. Here you have both INTERNAL_USERS or EXTERNAL_USERS data in TABLE_X with userType as the discriminator column. 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1191

Answer (score 0):

Given the table structure, you can use JPA Inheritance as detailed here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_joined_inheritance_annotations

In Hibernate you can model such relationships as follows. When querying for a User you can then rely on Hibernate to return an instance of the correct type.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User{

    @Id
    private Long userId;
}

@Entity
public class InternalUser extends User{


}

@Entity
public class ExternalUser extends User{


}
```

As noted in the article linked to, Hibernate does not require a discriminator column to be specified when using joined inheritance. It does however support a discriminator column if one is available. As you have one available in your schema - userType - then you could explicitly specify it if you wish. I imagine this would yield some performance benefit in terms of the generated SQL:

Mappings with optional discriminator column:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="userType")
public class User{

    @Id
    private Long userId;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INT")
public class InternalUser extends User{


}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EXT")
public class ExternalUser extends User{


}
```